# Can I run EaseUs Todo Backup recovery from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: backup

I purchased EaseUS Todo Backup 11.0 (upgrade) today. I really like the software, and the newest version made some improvements on the UI, so I felt it was worth the $15 upgrade price.

I have created a Todo Backup Linux recovery disk on a USB flash drive.
So if I want to recover my system, I need to insert this USB flash drive into a USB port. Simple enough.

But I got to thinking that since I already have Ubuntu 18.04 installed permanently on my HDD (dual-boot from Grub to Windows 7 or 10), why not just install a Todo Backup recovery utility in Ubuntu?
But there doesn't appear to be any such animal.
When I created the Linux recovery disc from Todo Backup, it downloades its own .iso file and burns a special version of Linux (not sure whether it's Ubuntu or not) that only runs the Todo Backup Recovery utility.

Any ideas?

Thanks

CP

Answer (score 2):

For starters, no, there is no linux version at the time of writing; I wish there was, as there don't seem to be any decent image-backup solution for linux just yet other than file-syncrhonizing ones.

The reason EasUs have a Linux iso to boot from is that when they created the first version there was no way to create a bootable repair tool based on Windows (now there is, with WinPE)... so it is partly historical.

In theory, though, there's nothing stopping you from creating a small partition on your hard drive and making the recovery iso bootable off of your hard-drive directly.

Just create a partition and copy the cd over, then simply update Grub to load it up accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

No. The reason Easeus wrapped their ToDo Backup around a Linux LiveUSB is because backup of Windows from within Windows means you would be able to open a lot of files to back them up. When you boot from Linux, that means Windows is shut down, and there aren't any open files in the Windows system which would not get backed up.

There are so many free open source backup solutions which work from within Linux for Linux that I am not surprised Easeus has not documented how to make it work from within a live system booted from the HD. Take a look at these... https://www.tecmint.com/linux-system-backup-tools/

Comment: The main reason I purchased EaseUS Todo Backup is that I mainly run Windows, and it is very easy to create and manage backups from within Windows.
It wasn't until this morning that I installed Ubuntu 18.04. I was running Ubuntu 14.04 a few years back as my main OS, but there were too many apps I needed to have, and they would only run on Windows.
I'm not sure what I am planning to do on Ubuntu now, but I like having it available.